# How to get "Allowed Content Types" of a DocumentSet by CSOM on SPO?

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, content-type, document-set

I have a SPO site with some DocumentSets having different ContentType.
I need to get "Allowed Content Types" of any DocumentSet to take a decision: I get my DocumentSet as ListItem or as Folder or as DocumentSet (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentSet) but, in any form it is, I can't find a way to reach the allowed Content Types, any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to get it through the [UniqueContentTypeOrder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee544103(v%3Doffice.15)) property.
Here's the part of the code that I used in one of the proejcts to get those values:

```
var docset = web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("DOCUMENTSETURL");
context.Load(docset);
context.Load(docset, l=> l.UniqueContentTypeOrder); 
context.ExecuteQuery();

foreach(var ctid in docset.UniqueContentTypeOrder)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ctid);
}
```